# Comparing Strings for match in a vectorized way

Tags: r, string, dataframe, vectorization

I have a large data frame, which contains two columns containing strings. When these columns are unequal, I want to do an operation.

The problem is that when I use a simple `!=` operator, it gives incorrect results. I.e. apparently, `'Tout_Inclus'` & `'Tout_Inclus'` are unequal.

This leads me to string comparison functions, like `strcmp` from pracma package. However, this is not vectorised - my dataframe has 9.6M rows, therefore I think this would crash/take ages if I looped through.

Has anyone got any vectorised methods for comparing strings?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    City_Break  City_Break
    City_Break  City_Break
    Court_Break Court_Break
    Petit_Budget    Petit_Budget
    Pas_Cher    Pas_Cher
    Deals   Deals_Pas_Chers
    Vacances    Vacances_Éco
    Hôtel_Vol   Hôtel_Vol
    Dernière_Minute Dernière_Minute
    Formule Formule_Éco
    Court_Séjour    Court_Séjour
    Voyage  Voyage_Pas_Cher
    Séjour  Séjour_Pas_Cher
    Congés  Congés_Éco
```

when I do something like `df[colA != colB,]` it gives incorrect results, where strings (by looking at them) are equal.

I've ensured encoding is `UTF-8`, strings are not factors, and I also tried removing special characters before doing the comparison.

By the way, these strings are from multiple languages.

edit: I've already trimmed whitespaces, and still no luck

Comment: Do you possibly have any leading/trailing whitespace in one/both of the columns?  Your `df[colA != colB,]` is correct, and should have worked.

Comment: Why do you assume that `strcmp` will give the desired results when `!=` doesn’t?

Comment: While your example `'Tout_Inclus'` would not be subject to this, to be general, there's also a possibility that accents were encoded differently on each side (resulting in same display but different character values), or that some non standard spaces were used on each side. I know too well that French characters are a pain to work with...

Comment: u can put those strings into two new vectors to compare in a loop, with fuzzy string matching algorithms, u can check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271685/fuzzy-matching-in-r and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/how-to-quasi-match-two-vectors-of-strings-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Try removing leading/trailing whitespace from both columns, and then compare:

```
df[trimws(df$colA, "both") != trimws(df$colB, "both"), ]
```

Comment: For a quick visual check one can also do `print(df, quote= TRUE)`

Comment: @Muddy_Moodskipper Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - thanks for the suggestion, but still no luck

Comment: @Tim496 OK...I will delete this once you get a correct answer then.  It might help others to leave it up for now.  Nice first name, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

If evertyhing else is fine(trim, etc..), yours could be an encoding problem. In UTF-8 the same accented character could be rapresented with different byte sequences. It may be single byte coded or with modifier byte. However, very strange with 'Tout_Inclus'.
Just to have a check, from *stringi* package try this:

```
stringi::stri_compare(df$colA,df$colB, "fr_FR")
```

What's the output?