# Replacing strings using fuzzywuzzyR

Tags: r, fuzzywuzzy

I have a large data set with city names. Many of the names are not consistent.

Example:

```
vec = c("New York", "New York City", "new York CIty", "NY", "Berlin", "BERLIn", "BERLIN", "London", "LONDEN", "Lond", "LONDON")
```

I want to use `fuzzywuzzyR` to bring them into a consistent format. The problem is I a have no master list of the original city names.

This package provides the possibility to detect duplicates like this:

```
library(fuzzywuzzyR)

init_proc = FuzzUtils$new() 
PROC = init_proc$Full_process   
init_scor = FuzzMatcher$new()    
SCOR = init_scor$WRATIO         
init = FuzzExtract$new()

init$Dedupe(contains_dupes = vec, threshold = 70L, scorer = SCOR)

dict_keys(['New York City', 'NY', 'BERLIN', 'LONDEN'])
```

Or I can set a "master value" like this:

```
master = "London"

init$Extract(string = master, sequence_strings = vec, processor = PROC, scorer = SCOR)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "London"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 100


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "LONDON"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 100


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "Lond"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 90


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "LONDEN"

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 83


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "NY"

[[5]][[2]]
[1] 45
```

My question is how can I use this to replace all matches in the list with the same value i.e. I would like to replace all values that match the master value with "London". However, I don´t have the master values. So, I need to have a list of matches and replace the values. In this case it would be "New York", "London" "Berlin". After the process, `vec` should looklike this.

```
new_vec = c("New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "Berlin", "Berlin", "Berlin", "London", "London", "London", "London")
```

**Update**

@camille came up with the idea of using `world.cities` of the `maps` package. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271685/fuzzy-matching-in-r) post using `fuzzyjoin` dealing with a similar problem.

To use this I convert `vec` to a data frame.

```
vec = as.data.frame(vec, stringsAsFactors = F) 
colnames(vec) = c("City")
```

Then using the `fuzzyjoin` package together with `world.cities` of the `maps` package.

```
library(maps)
library(fuzzyjoin)

vec %>%
  stringdist_left_join(world.cities, by = c(City = "name"), distance_col = "d") %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  top_n(1)
```

The output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 3
# Groups:   City [5]
   City     name         d
   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 New York New York     0
 2 NY       Ae           2
 3 NY       Al           2
 4 NY       As           2
 5 NY       As           2
 6 NY       As           2
 7 NY       Au           2
 8 NY       Ba           2
 9 NY       Bo           2
10 NY       Bo           2
# ... with 40 more rows
```

The Problem is that I have no Idea how to use the distance between ´name`and`City` to change the misspelled values into the right ones for all cities. In theory the corret value must be the closest one. But i.e. for NY this not the case.

Comment: I'm guessing in your full data there are too many cities / potentially changing cities to just make your own reference list? Or if the cities aren't too small or obscure, you might use the `world.cities` dataset that ships with the `maps` package---it's got about 44,000 cities and might work as a reference. But again, that depends on the scale of what you're working on.