# Give/Take a certain number of rows in a df back

Tags: r

I have the following issue:

1. I have two dfs, called `df1` and `df2`.
2. With the given `ifelse` function I try to find all rows in the `df2$Index` which starts with the same three characters as in `df1$Index_1`.
3. Search all cells starting with `CEE`.Then take all the growth values and the `df2$Index` values that are at `CEE` and one before (Period 1). etc. The df: Result1 shows what the final result (just for the first row) looks like.
4. The function should run through the entire vector Index_1 & Period. At the end there should be 5 dfs with the result.
5. The `ifelse` function should identify the start point, and if the point was founded, then it should use the number in the period list to give the Growth and `df2$Index` values back, as already mentioned above. I tried it with the `ifelse` function but I am sure there is a better and easier way to do this, moreover, the `iflese` function is not complete due to my lack of knowledge in R. It would be very nice if someone can help me.

```
Period <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Index_1 <- c("CEE","DAE","ABC","EBB","BDC")



Growth <- c(10:34)
Index <- c("ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB" )  

Df1 <- data.frame(Period, Index_1)
Df2 <- data.frame(Growth,Index)

ss <- as.data.frame(ifelse(substr(Df2$Index, 1,3) == df1$Index_1,1,0))

Result1 <- data.frame(Index, Growth)
Index <- c("BDCE","CEED","BDCE","CEED","BDCE","CEED","BDCE","CEED","BDCE","CEED")
Growth <- c(11,12,16,17,21,22,26,27,31,32)

Result2 <- data.frame(Index, Growth)
Index <- c("BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB")
Growth <- c(11,12,13,16,17,18,21,22,13,26,27,28,31,32,33)
```

Second Question

```
Period <- c(3,2,1,4,5)
Index_1 <- c("CEE","DAE","ABC","EBB","BDC")


Growth <- c(10:34)
Index <- c("ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED", "DAEB", "EBBB" )  

Df1 <- data.frame(Period, Index_1)
Df2 <- data.frame(Growth,Index)

lst <- apply(Df1, 1, function(x) {
  match_rows <- which(substr(Df2$Index, 1, 3) == x[["Index_1"]])
  all_rows <- unlist(Map(`:`, match_rows - as.numeric(x[["Period"]]), match_rows))
  Df2[all_rows[all_rows > 0],]
})

lst[[1]] # This is how it looks now

#and this is how it should look like
Result3 <- data.frame(Index, Growth) 
Index <- c("NA","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED","EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED","EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED","EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED","EBBB","ABCD","BDCE", "CEED")
Growth <- c(NA,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27)
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271685/fuzzy-matching-in-r & https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/FuzzyMergeR101.pdf

Comment: At a certain point yes! But what I need additionally is to consider the period. If you read the result1 or 2 df you will see the difference. Let my code run and (without the ifelse function) and you will see what I try to achieve. Thank you for your help! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach in base R. You can use `apply` to go through each row of `Df1`, and get the row numbers of matching rows in `Df2`. Then, you can take these matching values and expand based on `Period` (getting a range of values, such as 2 additional rows if `Period` is 2).

It is not exactly clear what to do if matching one of the first rows (with the `Period` offset). What if the first row of `Df2` matches but `Period` is 5? So I just use rows that are available and subsetted where row positions are greater than zero. The end result is a list of data.frames.

```
lst <- apply(Df1, 1, function(x) {
  match_rows <- which(substr(Df2$Index, 1, 3) == x[["Index_1"]])
  all_rows <- unlist(Map(`:`, match_rows - as.numeric(x[["Period"]]), match_rows))
  Df2[all_rows[all_rows > 0],]
})

> lst[[1]]
   Growth Index
2      11  BDCE
3      12  CEED
7      16  BDCE
8      17  CEED
12     21  BDCE
13     22  CEED
17     26  BDCE
18     27  CEED
22     31  BDCE
23     32  CEED

> lst[[2]]
   Growth Index
2      11  BDCE
3      12  CEED
4      13  DAEB
7      16  BDCE
8      17  CEED
9      18  DAEB
12     21  BDCE
13     22  CEED
14     23  DAEB
17     26  BDCE
18     27  CEED
19     28  DAEB
22     31  BDCE
23     32  CEED
24     33  DAEB
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is exactly what I wanted. :-) There is no case in my df's that this will happen!

Comment: My bad, Indeed I got something like you mentioned before. It should be filled out with Na's if this is possible?

Comment: Thank you ;-). Maybe you have also and idea to another issue. After Df2[all_rows[all_rows > 0],]  I wrote the following chunk to get after each run the list splitted to equal part: max <- Period
x <- seq_along(Df2$Growth)
d1 <- split(Df2$Growth, ceiling(x/max)), but it doesn't work! because I want to calculate the maxDrawdown. As an example: The first result (lst[[1]]) CEED and BDCE occurs 5 times, and I need to calculate the maxDD for each of those 5 parts, do you understand what I try to explain?

Comment: This is a bit confusing --- first, if you fill in with `NA`, what exactly should this look like? Can you edit your original question with what the output should be for `Period` of 3 (in which case this problem occurs)? Then, with calculating "maxDrawdown" - I'm not sure I follow. That could also be a separate question. If you post the code you're using, and indicate what the final result should look like, I'm sure I or someone else will be able to answer...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will update my original question in a few minutes and opening a new question with the word maxDrawdown in it.

Comment: Your `Result3` cannot be created, as `Index` and `Growth` vectors are different lengths. Also you have "Na" in quotes, but I think you just want `NA` instead? Once you create your `Result3` on exactly as it should look like, you can do `dput(Result3)` and then copy/paste the result into your question. It makes things easier for others to reproduce...

Comment: You can‘t reproduce this result, because it shows just how it should looks like! If you change at the period vector the first number (1) trough 3 you will get the result how it looks like with your function and my result which I already posted is how it should looks like. But I can also do it, I am just on the way home (using my cellphone).

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a `pattern` to search for with `str_detect`
2. `filter` for this `pattern`
3. Use window function `lead` and `lag` and
4. filter with `if_any` to `fulfill` request 3
5. group to sets of 3 and
6. use `group_split` to fulfill request 4

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

pattern <- paste(Df1$Index_1, collapse = "|")

Df2 %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Index, pattern)) %>% 
    mutate(x = lead(Index),
           y = lag(Index)) %>% 
    filter(if_any(c(Index, x, y), ~str_detect(., "^CEE"))) %>% 
    select(Index, Growth) %>% 
    mutate(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
    group_split(group)
```

output:

```
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    Index : character
    Growth: integer
    group : integer
  >
>[5]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Index Growth group
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 BDCE      11     1
2 CEED      12     1
3 DAEB      13     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Index Growth group
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 BDCE      16     2
2 CEED      17     2
3 DAEB      18     2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Index Growth group
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 BDCE      21     3
2 CEED      22     3
3 DAEB      23     3

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Index Growth group
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 BDCE      26     4
2 CEED      27     4
3 DAEB      28     4

[[5]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Index Growth group
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 BDCE      31     5
2 CEED      32     5
3 DAEB      33     5
```